# Javascript - Deep Links for App Content

Tags: javascript, android, ios, deep-linking

i have a website and relatives iOS and Android apps.

When user from mobile device clicks on a my content shared in fb or twitter,it is redirect to the website. Then, i implemented a script to find out whether the device has the application installed otherwise open the market (google play or iOS app store).

The script is:

```
deepLink: function (contentId, store) {
        if (contentId && contentId != '')
            window.location.href = "my_app://" + contentId;
        else
            window.location.href = "my_app://";

        $timeout(function () { window.location.href = store; }, 25);
    }
```

Where "contentId" is the id of the detail page and "store" is the URL of android or iOS market.

This does not work because it opens the app but also opens the market.
I want open only the app or only the market if the app is not installed.
Is there a solution? I have already read that it is **always recommended redirect** to the app store, and not directly to the app but the customer asked me specifically this feature.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="hotstar" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Can someone help me? thx

Comment: In order to achieve what you want, you surely implemented some `intent-filters` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`? Please post your `AndroidManifest.xml` file (the relevant part of it).

Comment: I updated your question. Next time, please edit your question. This amount of XML in a comment makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript PageVisibility Api you can check whether a browser tab is being viewed. In your case ,in the timeout function, before redirecting to store check if the tab is being viewed using pagevisibility. If page is not being viewed it means your deeplink worked and app was opened. So you don't have to redirect to store.